# Angular (Material UI) - format ssn on user input

Tags: angular

I have the following problem. I have ssn input which has to be formatted like **xxx-xx-xxxx** and I can achieve this using pipe transformation

````
    <mat-label>SSN</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text" [ngModel]="ssn | ssn" (ngModelChange)="transformSsn($event)">
  </mat-form-field>import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'ssn'
})
export class SsnPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(a: string, ...args: unknown[]): unknown {
    var fSSN = '';
    fSSN += a.substr(0, 3);
    fSSN += '-' + a.substr(3, 2);
    fSSN += '-' + a.substr(5, 4);
    return fSSN;
  }

}```

But somehow I have to distinguish viewValue, which has to be xxx-xx-xxxx with modelValue which has to be xxxxxxxx( simple number). I've tried to add transformSsn function call on modelChanges event, but still no luck. Any help would be highly appreciated.
````

Answer (score 0):

What if you expand the `transform()` to check if string `a` already contains some `-`'s? And if so return and do nothing? You could of course expand this if check the check if the `-`'s are in exact index that you want, but the point is same.

```js
  transform(a: string, ...args: unknown[]): unknown {

    if (a.includes('-') return;

    var fSSN = '';
    fSSN += a.substr(0, 3);
    fSSN += '-' + a.substr(3, 2);
    fSSN += '-' + a.substr(5, 4);
    return fSSN;
  }
```